# WWW::Mechanize to access secure website

Tags: oracle, perl

I have a script I am trying to log into an Oracle EBS page with and I believe I am one line away, (I could be wrong) from doing this. Below is my script and attached is the section of from data I think the answer is there some where.

I think its the submit and submit form line where I think I am failing. But if anyone sees other discrepancies, please let me know. I do see where the username in the script is in the form but not the password. I do believe the script has the right entry, but correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks in advance!

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Cookies;
my $outfile = "test";
my $url = "http ://url_address:portnumber /OA_HTML/Login";
my $username = 'johndoe';
my $password = 'johndoe123';
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());
$mech->get($url);
$mech->form_id('DefaultFormName');
$mech->field("usernameField", $username);
$mech->field("passwordField", $password);
$mech->submit_form(

form_id => "DefaultFormName",
fields => {
    usernameField => $username,
    passwordField => $password,
    '_FORM_SUBMIT_BUTTON' => "SubmitButtonofEPmL1A",
},
);
my $output_page = $mech->content();
print $output_page;
open(OUTFILE, ">$outfile");
binmode(OUTFILE, ":utf8");`enter code here`
print OUTFILE "$output_page";
close(OUTFILE);
```

Form snipet:

```
"name="usernameField" size="0" type="text" value="johndoe">
< src="/OA_HTML/cabo/images/swan/t.gif" width="5"></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"></td><td><span class="x2o">
(example: john.doe)</span></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr id="region41" align="left"><td id="region131" valign="top"><span class="x9g">*</span></td>
<td id="region51" valign="top"><span class="x9c">Password</span></td><td id="region61"><table id="passwordField__xc_" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td align="right" nowrap></td><td></td>
<td valign="top" nowrap><input id="passwordField" title="Password" class=".LoginText" onchange="" name="passwordField" size="0" type="password">
< src="/OA_HTML/cabo/images/swan/t.gif" width="5"></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"></td><td><span class="x2o">
(example: A1B2c3D4)</span></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr id="region132" align="left"><td id="region139">
</td><td id="region138"></td><td id="region133">
<button id="SubmitButton" title="Login" class="x7g" style="background-image:url(/OA_HTML/cabo/images/swan/btn-bg1.gif)" 
onclick="submitForm('DefaultFormName',1,{'_FORM_SUBMIT_BUTTON':'SubmitButtonofEPmL1A'});return false" type="submit">Login</button>< id="item11" src="/OA_HTML/cabo/images/swan/t.gif" width="2" height="1">"
```

Answer (score 2):

WWW::Mechanize does not handle JavaScript. If JavaScript is involved (and it seems so, `onclick="submitForm...`), use some other module (e.g. [WWW::Mechanize::Firefox](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aFirefox)).

Comment: Noteworthy: That Mech doesn't handle JavaScript is the very first question in the [WWW::Mechanize FAQ](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize/FAQ.pod)

Comment: Any suggestions what will then?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this lines (`WWW::Mechanize` will work with cookies for you automatically):

```
use HTTP::Cookies;
$mech->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());
```

Next... Are you sure your link have this **text**: `submitForm`? May be you need:

```
$mech->follow_link( url_regex => qr/submitForm/ );
```

I recommend to try this code instead (for submit part):

```
$mech->submit_form(

    form_id => "DefaultFormName",
    fields => {
        usernameField => $username,
        passwordField => $password,
        '_FORM_SUBMIT_BUTTON' => "SubmitButtonofEPmL1A",
    },
};
```

**Update:** Another way: you need to use tool like Firefox's HTTPFox add-on and find what data is send to the target site after each request. Next you simply send same data with `$mech`.

Comment: Thanks gangabass, I had a similar script that accessed a similar site as Oracle EBS URL and it worked fine, so i just modified the information to fit the EBS site and it seemed to have worked up to the point of the submit. So after going crosseyed reading the form data, i believed i was missing the line or two regarding submit or click. I will try your suggestion Thanks! BTW, do you see any clues in the form data i provided?

Comment: See my original post where i added the lines you suggested. It seems like we went backwards as in the output file i am not seeing the username in the form as we did before.